# Flask - Dump exceptions to debug later

Tags: python, flask

Sometimes in production one can experience some errors raising exceptions for example Flask. One of the solutions is to log the exception using `logging.exception`. but it's not sufficient to reproduce the issue.

That would be nice if we can dump the exception into a file to debug later, to explore objects. do python able to do that ? something like core dump ?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the complete stack trace to a file in case of exception. 
You can create a function for your app instance that will log exceptions. In this example all exceptions in your app or sqllachemy package will be logged in "sample.log" file.

```
def log(app):

    import logging
    from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
    from logging import getLogger
    logging._defaultFormatter = logging.Formatter(u"%(message)s")
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    file_handler = RotatingFileHandler("sample.log", maxBytes=1024*1024*10,     backupCount=100)

    loggers = [app.logger, getLogger('sqlalchemy')]
    for logger in loggers:
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

In the init script of your application after creating an app instance just
call the created function

```
log(app)
```